# Using media field from Page in an extension 

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

We all may know the following snippet that gets the first entry of the media field of a page to e.g. display a header image on a page.

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file {
  import = uploads/media/
  import.data = levelmedia: 0, slide
  import.listNum = 0
}
```

I am creating an extension (plugin, no ItemuserFunc etc) which needs to work with this media. I don't want to process dozens of typoscript directives in php to create this images. How can I use the example above to process the media field through typoscript, using core functionality instead of reinventing the wheel?

So now I'm in my extension code, having an array of page records. How to get further? The code below doesn't provide the functionality I need because I am not working on the page level (like I would when using the TS from above in a TMENU).

```
$content .= $this->cObj->stdWrap($page['media'], $this->conf['media_stdWrap.']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an array of page records (`$pages`) with the associative keys same as the field names in the database, mainly the *media* field, you would simply walk through the array and create the images using the Typoscript configuration.

### Example 1 (a programmer sets the rendering)

```
foreach($pages as $value) {
  $mediaField = t3lib_div::trimExplode(',', $value['media']);
  if(!$mediaField[0]) continue;

  $imageConf = array(
    'file' => 'uploads/media/' . $mediaField[0],
  );
  $content .= $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle('IMAGE', $imageConf);
}
```

### Example 2 (an editor sets the rendering)

```
foreach($pages as $value) {
  $this->cObj->data = $value;
  $content .= $this->cObj->stdWrap($value['media'], $this->conf['media_stdWrap.']);
}
```

It sets the page data so that they are available as `field` in Typoscript. The configuration would then look something like this:

```
{
  media_stdWrap {
    cObject = IMAGE
    cObject {
      file {
        import = uploads/media/
        import.field = media
        import.listNum = 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Example 3 (combination of the previous 2 examples)

```
foreach($pages as $value) {
  $mediaField = t3lib_div::trimExplode(',', $value['media']);
  $mediaOutput = '';

  // Creating the output with a default rendering
  if($mediaField[0]) {
    $imageConf = array(
      'file' => 'uploads/media/' . $mediaField[0],
    );
    $mediaOutput = $this->cObj->cObjGetSingle('IMAGE', $imageConf);
  }

  // Allowing custom Typoscript to completely modify the media part
  if(array_key_exists('media_stdWrap.', $this->conf)) {
    $this->cObj->data = $value;
    $mediaOutput = $this->cObj->stdWrap($mediaOutput, $this->conf['media_stdWrap.']);
  }

  $content .= $mediaOutput;
}
```

**NOTE**: These examples are completely untested. I've came up with them out of my head.

Comment: Could you explain "can work as well with modified configuration" ? Your solution is solid, thanks, but I'm wondering. I don't want to loose flexibility,

Comment: By user you mean an editor/webmaster? You can load his configuration and include it in the `$imageConf` to let him alter the output.

Comment: "can work as well with modified configuration" = `$imageConf` would need to have different structure but at the end both should give you the same result.

Comment: yup, sorry, stated unclear. I thought of having the same flexibility like I would have in a TMENU (using COA etc). Your solution limits to IMAGE. I wanted to know if there is a possibility to let some function return the generated output a user created in his typsocript, e.g. with COA, Images, different wraps etc.

Comment: Well, yes you can give them complete flexibility. The only thing is that they might then try to access data that is not available in the context you are doing the things (e.g. `levelmedia`). Let me come up with another example.

Comment: woohoo, thanks. The `$this->cObj->data = $value;` part was what I tried to figure out. I would upvote more than once if I could.

Comment: Example 3 is the most advanced as it combines your (default) rendering while allowing an editor to modify the output (e.g. by wrapping it) or completely override it with his own.